# Buttons not working on mobile using React

Tags: javascript, node.js, reactjs

I deployed a dummy gatsby project on gatsby.io and it works fine on my laptop but when i view it from my phone, none of the buttons seem to be working. It also doesn't seem to recognise scroll events, almost like there's no functionality in the site.

**Note:** The site works perfectly fine on my laptop

Here's the link to the dummy site
https://drivingwebsite.gatsbyjs.io/

Comment: There's an error in the console (`Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'apply')`), if you open the DevTools. Since `Gatsby` is essentially React/JavaScript app, any unhandled JavaScript might break the overall functionality. Try to catch it first.

Comment: Nvm i found the bug, I was using redux dev tools extension during development but forgot to remove it for production. Since i had the extension on my laptop, the site loaded without any errors but didn't work on my phone. I just removed the code related to the redux dev tools extension and everything seems to be working fine now.